# Отсутствует соединение приложения по сети (Украина)

Tags: java, vkontakte-api

Создаю приложение по VK API и так как с Украины, мой оператор заблокировал доступ в vk.

VPN в опере включен, но не понимаю как сделать так, чтобы программа имела доступ к vk.

Ошибку выдает `java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect`

Как можно исправить?

Comment: Хм, соединение возможно, но на той стороне нет прослушки. Пока не знаю, чем помочь. Добавьте в вопрос больше информации.

Comment: Ну сделаете поддержку вк. И кто ею будет пользоваться? Правильно - никто. Но если очень-очень сильно хочется - используйте vpn, который для всей системы. Но все это никому не нужно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исправить можно следующим образом:
Использовать VPN на уровне операционной системы, т.к. ваше приложение использует системное подключение к сети(а оно у вас без VPN), а не подключение Оперы(которое у вас через VPN)

Попробуйте бесплатный(500Гб) VPN: https://www.tunnelbear.com/

ещё вариант: https://antizapret.prostovpn.org/

специально для Украины --==>> https://zaborona.help/

Answer (score 2):

Вы сказали "ВПН в опере включен". Если вы запускаете vpn содинение из браузера, то и все исходящие сетевые запросы, сделанные браузером (!) пойдут через vpn. Остальная часть операционной системы (другие приложения) будут работать по старому. Вам нужно настроить vpn на уровне системы, а не браузера.